# fetch json, error al pasar variables y obtener datos

Tags: javascript, laravel

para ponerlos en contexto, tengo 2 tablas que no tienen relación una a la otra.
lo que necesito hacer es que en un select mostrar los datos de ambas tablas (ese no es el problema), el problema erradica en la siguiente consulta.

**Controlador "x"**:

```
  public function sbu_obtener_base($datos){
    $sbu_ajax = DB::table('tabla_sbu_otros')->where('abreviatura',  $datos)->first();
    $sbu_usuario_ajax = DB::table('tabla_sbu_usuario')->where('abreviatura',  $datos)->first();
    return response()->json(array( $sbu_ajax, $sbu_usuario_ajax));  //aqui paso las variables en array por que no se como pasarlas.
    // return response()->json($sbu_ajax); // esta linea es la forma correcta
}
```

no se como pasar de forma correcta las variables `$sbu_ajax`  `$sbu_usuario_ajax` lo que hice fue ponerlas en un array.

**javascript**:

```
function OpcionChange(identidad, receptor, costo_hora, grupo_ocu,){
var valores = document.getElementById(identidad).value;
fetch('/api/base/'+valores+'/opcion')
.then((response) => response.json()).then((dato)=>{   
    dato.forEach(dato => {
        console.log(dato)

    document.getElementById(receptor).innerHTML=`<span>$ ${dato.RMU}</span>`
    document.getElementById(costo_hora).innerHTML=`<span>$ ${dato.RMU_mes}</span>`
    document.getElementById(grupo_ocu).innerHTML=`<span>${dato.grupo_ocupacional}</span>`    
    })
})}
```

resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

los datos de la `T1 = tabla_sbu_otros` si lo realiza, el de la otra tabla `T2 = tabla_sbu_usuario` no me envía datos, envía `undefined`.

> si invierto el orden de las variables en el controlador, se invierte el problema. y la cosa es que no se como identificar cuando pedir los datos de la tabla 1 y cuando de la tabla 2.

CONSOLA cuando selecciono valor de T1
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CONSOLA cuando selecciono valor de T2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías editar la pregunta para mostrar qué retorna en la consola el response?

Comment: @padaleiana, listo.

Comment: La variable `valores` que recupera? el valor del select option?

Comment: si es prácticamente con lo que identifico que abreviatura es por que, si lo hago por id  puede repetir en las dos tablas.

'/api/base/SVP1'/opcion'

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que la segunda consulta a la bd (que se guarda en $sbu_usuario_ajax) devuelve algún valor? Tendrías que verificar el valor de $sbu_usuario_ajax antes del return response() [...] .

Comment: @padaleiana, 
asi esta ahora:
return response()->json(array( $sbu_ajax, $sbu_usuario_ajax));
si invierto las variables, si me envia datos y la segunda no.

Comment: ($variable1 , $variable2), me envia datos de la primera variable la segunda no me muestra nada pero si lo pongo en el navegador si http://localhost:8000/api/base/USSV1/opcion me muestra los datos en json de la segunda.

Comment: Desde Laravel puedes chequear que no sea el método first() que devuelve `null`, pues lo hará si la consulta no devuelve resultados. También intentar armando el array para la respuesta json  poniendo nombres a los índices , como lo muestran en la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/responses#json-responses),

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ , amigo la consulta si devuelve datos, lo que pasa es que devuelve 2 array, y el asunto es como mostrar el segundo array sin problema, el first() me devuelve esa única fila no necesito todas cuando hago la petición ese no es el problema. el problema esta en como envio los datos, y como los recibo, lo otro que recomiendas ya lo hice y termina siendo en teoria lo mismo, ahora seria como mostrar los datos despues.

Answer (score 4):

Interpretando tu código en JS, veo que estás llamando a `.then()` "de seguido" en lugar de llamarlo con `response.json().then()`[...]. Es decir, deberías corregirlo para que aparezca así:

```
function OpcionChange(identidad, receptor, costo_hora, grupo_ocu) {
  var valores = document.getElementById(identidad).value;
  fetch("/api/base/" + valores + "/opcion").then((response) =>
    response.json().then((datos) => { //modifiqué por "datos" para mejor legibilidad
      datos.forEach((dato) => {
        console.log(dato);

        document.getElementById(receptor).innerHTML = `<span>$ ${dato.RMU}</span>`;
        document.getElementById(costo_hora).innerHTML = `<span>$ ${dato.RMU_mes}</span>`;
        document.getElementById(grupo_ocu).innerHTML = `<span>${dato.grupo_ocupacional}</span>`;
      });
    }));
}
```

Se debe invocar de esta manera ya que `response.json()` retorna una promesa, y es por eso que estás obteniendo `undefined`, ya que los resultados "aún no están listos" como para visualizarlos.

**EDIT**: Dado que el controlador está retornando un array de objetos:

`datos[0]`: contiene el objeto retornado en `$sbu_ajax`,

`datos[1]`: contiene el objeto retornado en `$sbu_usuario_ajax`.

Comment: sigue igual, el asunto es que envía en 2 posiciones diferentes los de la tabla 1 en posición 0 (esas me las muestra en pantalla) y la T2 en posición 1 (esas solo me las muestra por consola)
https://prnt.sc/s08bkl

Comment: Tratando de sintetizar: haciendo los cambios, entonces tenés:
T1[0] = con datos, T1[1] = null;  T2[0] = null, T2[1] con datos. ¿Así?

Comment: ambos me dan datos, por pantalla solo me muestran los datos en posición [0]. por consola si se muestran cuando hago el select.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar cómo estás intentando mostrar los datos que obtenés de la petición en las tablas?

Comment: todo lo que estoy haciendo y utilizando esta publicado, en teoría no he modificado nada, solo lo que me aconsejaste. y uso un foreach para enviar los datos, por que como puse en el post, no se si esta bien enviando los datos desde el controlador y eso esta al inicio.

Comment: Respuesta editada.

Comment: si puedo verlo, una consulta, olvido agregar algo en el código o solo quería aclarar que así se están recibiendo los datos?

Comment: Lo segundo. la modificación ya la había hecho en la respuesta original.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106765/discussion-between-duvalad-and-padaleiana).